# How to update one drive file using SharePoint CSOM C# code programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, onedrive-for-business, onedrive

I am looking for a way to update the one drive file or document using some SharePoint CSOM code. So can we achieve this using CSOM or some C# code?

I have even tried to load one drive site collection URL using the below code but I am not able to find the actual list from where I can access the stored files from one drive.

One Drive Site URL : https://{tenant}.my.sharepoint.com/personal/pravin_{tenant}_com

```
using (ClientContext clientcontext = new ClientContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"]))
{
                Web web = clientcontext.Web;
                clientcontext.Load(clientcontext.Web.Lists);
                clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (List list in clientcontext.Web.Lists)
                {
                       var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
                       clientcontext.Load(items);
                       clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

                       foreach (var docItem in items)
                       {
                          //Here, I want to update the one drive file and upload it again using some sort of code.
                       }
                }
}
```

Please suggest the code or other ways using which we can update the one drive files programmatically.

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is stored in the List Documents.

```
List list = clientcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
clientcontext.Load(list);
clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me.

Comment: If my reply helps you, you could accept it as answer.